# Layout wont stretch according to div size

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm learning some angularjs and I'm building a small project.
It mostly connects to a DB and load a table to the website, each row represent a project (assume...).

I'm doing it with angularjs, loading an array, encoding it to JSON and presenting it, but - it seems that the DIV is cut off, showing properly only the first line and adding a scrollbar.

I want the DIV to strech according to the number of elemnts I show.

This part of the code look like this :

```
<div id="topContainer" ng-controller="projectController">
        <h3>{{ projectsNum }} Live projects</h3>
        <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
            <project-information info="project"></project-information>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css :

```
#topContainer {
    overflow: auto;
}

#proj {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Please create a demo of the issue instead of posting dynamic code.

Comment: I'm running it on a local server on my computer, here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8ekZyxe.jpg 
Sorry about the "style" just coloring it so I can notice...

Comment: Copy the HTML generated in the browser and post it here. Use Firebug or ChromeDevTools and right click on the element.

Answer (score 0):

**Table Layout Solution**

Give the parent container `table` layout and child items `table-cell`. Give `100%` width to the parent.

```css
#topContainer {
  overflow: auto;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#proj {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="topContainer" ng-controller="projectController">
  <h3>8 Live projects</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      First
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Second
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Third
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Fourth
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Fifth
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Sixth
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Seventh
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Eighth
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Flexbox Layout Solution**

Wrap the projects in a separate container and use the [**Flexbox Layout Module**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Check the [**Browser compatibility table**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) for Flexbox

```css
#topContainer {
  overflow: auto;
}
#proj {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1; /* Grow and Shrink according to the parent */
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="topContainer" ng-controller="projectController">
  <h3>8 Live projects</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      First
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Second
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Third
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Fourth
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Fifth
    </div><div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Sixth
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Seventh
    </div>
    <div id="proj" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      Eighth
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```